# Cloudify REST API 2.7: with and without version

Tags: api, rest, cloudify

I’m working on Cloudify REST API v2.7 (http://getcloudify.org/guide/2.7/restapi/restdoclet.html).

What is the difference between the APIs starting with “/version/…” and those starting without “/version/…”?

For example, what is the difference between the following API:

- /{version}/deployments/applications/description
- /service/applications

Answer (score 1):

The Rest API was practically re-written in version 2.7 . The APIs starting with "/version" are the updated APIs and they are also the ones used by the CLI. You should use them. The "/service" APIs are mostly deprecated.